# args discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

If I typed `+sendtextbutton` and then I said *hello* I want my bot to send the button with what I said (hello). In this case `args` is right, but I have a problem. When I type anything after the command the bot sends the button with the command and the `args`.

[image]

this is my code :

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`+sendtextbutton`)) {
    if (!config.bot.owners.includes(`${message.author.id}`)) {
      if(!args [0] ) return message.react("❌")
      return;
    }
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    let text = args.join(' ')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0x0099FF)
            .setTitle('press the button');
            //.setDescription('');
    let button = new MessageButton()
      .setLabel(`${text}`)
      .setStyle(`LINK`)
      .setURL(`youtube.com`)
      .setEmoji(``)

    let row = new MessageActionRow()
      .setComponents(button)
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `args` is the whole message sent, you probably forgot to remove the first part (`+sendtextbutton`). You'll need to remove the first item from the `args` array before you `join` them:

```js
if (!config.bot.owners.includes(`${message.author.id}`)) {
  // ! it doesn't do anything, args is not defined at this point
  if (!args[0]) return message.react('❌');
  return;
}
const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift(); //=> +sendtextbutton

let text = args.join(' '); //=> it's everything sent after +sendtextbutton
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  // ...
```